# HLS security token (Authorization)

Tags: php, streaming, http-live-streaming, rtmp, hls.js

I was able to measure a stream using ffmpeg on the server side and display it on the user side with the hls.js library.

## i used php for a server side

But now I have a problem, I want to increase the security of the stream with a token.
I did a lot of searches on Google, and I noticed that they put things like wmsAuthSign or signature in the payload of the requests.
But I don't know how to create them on server and client side.